# dplyr & monetdb - appropriate syntax for querying schema.table?

Tags: r, dplyr, monetdb

In `monetdb` I have set up a schema `main`  and my tables are created into this schema.

For example, the `department` table is `main.department`.

With `dplyr` I try to query the table:

```
mdb <- src_monetdb(dbname="model", user="monetdb", password="monetdb")

tbl(mdb, "department")
```

But I get

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  Unable to execute statement 'PREPARE SELECT * FROM "department"'.
Server says 'SELECT: no such table 'department'' [#42S02].
```

I tried to use `"main.department"`  and other similar combinations with no luck.

What is the appropriate syntax?

Comment: What is the output of `dbListTables(mdb$con)`  (or `db_list_tables(mdb$con)`?

Comment: `dbListTables()` is implemented in monetdb to lists all the tables except system tables, and this is what I see.

Comment: what do you see ? I didn't see any output. In addition, what is also the result of `select current_schema;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a somewhat hacky workaround for this: We can manually set the default schema for the connection. I have a database `testing`, in there is a schema `foo` with a table called `bar`.

```
mdb <- src_monetdb("testing")
dbSendQuery(mdb$con, "SET SCHEMA foo");
t <- tbl(mdb, "bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dbplyr` package (a backend of `dplyr` for database connections) has a `in_schema()` function for these cases:

```
conn <- dbConnect(
  MonetDB.R(),
  host = "localhost",
  dbname = "model",
  user = "monetdb",
  password = "monetdb",
  timeout = 86400L
)

department = tbl(conn, dbplyr::in_schema("main", "department"))
```